# What is the correct way to specify dimensions in DIP from Java code?

Tags: android, layout, density-independent-pixel

I found that it is possible to set dimensions of my interface elements in XML layouts using DIPs as in following fragment:

```
android:layout_width="10dip"
```

But all Java interface takes integer as arguments and there is no way to specify dimensions in DIPs. What is the correct way to calculate this?

I figured that I have to use property density of `DisplayMetrics` class but is this a correct way?

May I rely on this formula being always correct?

> pixels * DisplayMetrics.density = dip

Is there a utility function for the conversion somewhere in Android?

Answer (score 92):

There is an existing utility method built called [`TypedValue.applyDimensions(int, float, DisplayMetrics)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html) that does this.

Here's how to use it:

```
// returns the number of pixels for 123.4dip
int value = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                     (float) 123.4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

There's a list of other types that you can use with it including `COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`,  `COMPLEX_UNIT_PT` all found in the page I linked above. If you exclude the (int) typecast, you'll get the floating point number.

I encountered the same problem and found this through poking around the code.

Comment: This converts pixels into DIP rather than DIP into pixels which I believe is what the OP wanted. Certainly it was what I wanted. Which you do like so: `(int)(desiredDIP * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)`

Answer (score 46):

That is the correct formula there. Although `DisplayMetrics.density` is not a static member, so, according to the [same document you alluded to](http://d.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels), correct usage is:

```
// Maybe store this in a static field?
final float SCALE = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

// Convert dips to pixels
float valueDips = 16.0f;
int valuePixels = (int)(valueDips * SCALE + 0.5f); // 0.5f for rounding
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, I somehow overlooked this part. There are two extra topic-related questions :

- will the density be always equal for both dimensions ? It seems so (as this is just one value), but perhaps there is some other formula for calculating this. 

- isn't there any API to do the conversion for me ? Do I really have to write the following snipped in my code ? In XML layout code, it is possible to specify "dip" as unit, why it's not possible in Java API ?

Comment: I think you can safely assume density being equal in both dimensions. Remember, DisplayMetrics.density is the **logical density**, not the actual screen density (which may slightly vary from the logical density). Regarding a conversion API, it's trivial to write a helper method like say, `Util.dip` that converts dip's to pixels for use in function calls. It's cleaner to handle units in Java that way anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Using the display metrics density field, you can get a scaling factor to convert to/from dips. Use the Math.round method to convert from a float to an int without needing a cast or adding 0.5

```
// Converting dips to pixels
float dips = 20.0f;
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = Math.round(dips * scale);

// Converting pixels to dips
int pixels = 15;
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dips = pixels / scale;
```

Comment: Math.round does do a cast. `(int)Math.floor(a + 0.5f)` is what Math.round does under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way is not to define any dimensions in code, but use the `values/dimens.xml` file instead. You can always define your dimension in the desired unit like:

```
<dimen name="my_layout_height">120dp</dimen>
```

and then refer to this in your Activity like:

```
getResources().getDimensions(R.dimen.my_layout_height);
```

This would return **pixels** after doing the necessary conversions. And also of course you can refer to this in your other XMLs like:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/my_layout_height"
```