# Set margins in a LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android, layout, view, margin

I'm trying to use Java (*not XML*) to create a LinearLayout with buttons that fill the screen, and have margins. Here is code that works without margins:

```
LinearLayout buttonsView = new LinearLayout(this);
buttonsView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
for (int r = 0; r < 6; ++r) {
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("A");

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); // Verbose!
    lp.weight = 1.0f; // This is critical. Doesn't work without it.
    buttonsView.addView(btn, lp);
}

ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
setContentView(buttonsView, lp);
```

So that works fine, but how on earth do you give the buttons margins so there is space between them? I tried using `LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams`, but that has no `weight` member so it's no good. And it doesn't work if you pass it `lp` in its constructor either.

Is this impossible? Because it sure looks it, and it wouldn't be the first Android layout task you can only do in XML.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins(int, int, int, int) Instead of layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0); you put layoutParams.setMargins(30dp, 20dp, 30dp, 0dp);

Comment: setMargins takes int as arguments.. you can only provide "dp" using xml attributtes

Answer (score 520, accepted):

Here is a little code to accomplish it:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

Button okButton=new Button(this);
okButton.setText("some text");
ll.addView(okButton, layoutParams);
```

Comment: Its possible to give the margins for the widgets in code too.

Comment: thanks for a to-the-point code sample - way more beneficial than just descriptions

Comment: It looks like the margin params are set in pixels. Any way to set them in dps?

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii Like most functions in Android, they take pixels. I suggest a global utility function that converts dips to px. This is what I have done in all my apps. Android API sucks.

Comment: @MaxHowell That's what I ended up doing. It's incredible that basic things like that are missing sometimes.

Comment: Is there a way of setting margin directly on a button e.g. myButton.setMargins(...) instead of having to nest the button in a linear layout?

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii - use TypedValue.applyDimension(...) to convert DIP to PX.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-specify-dimensions-in-dip-from-java-code

Comment: it reqires min API 11

Comment: I have also used this way to convert dp to pixel: getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.col_2d3), which was declared in dimen.xml like <dimen name="col_2d3">10dp</dimen>. It is converted to 20 pixels on my device.

Comment: If you want your design to scale to any screen you can set the widths of components to some fraction of the screen width. So if you want 4 buttons across the screen, make each of their widths a quarter of the screen width. You can even do this with text.

Comment: margin_30 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

Answer (score 63):

> So that works fine, but how on earth
>   do you give the buttons margins so
>   there is space between them?

You call `setMargins()` on the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` object.

> I tried using
>   LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams, but
>   that has no weight member so it's no
>   good.

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams` is a subclass of `LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams`, as indicated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html).

> Is this impossible?

No.

> it wouldn't be the first Android
>   layout task you can only do in XML

You are welcome to supply proof of this claim.

Personally, I am unaware of anything that can only be accomplished via XML and not through Java methods in the SDK. In fact, by definition, everything has to be doable via Java (though not necessarily via SDK-reachable methods), since XML is not executable code. But, if you're aware of something, point it out, because that's a bug in the SDK that should get fixed someday.

Comment: Ha, ok I understand now. Was getting a bit lost in the layout system which is rather complicated. I don't think there's anyway to set layout_widgth/height at runtime.

Comment: And there's no way to set the style: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view

Comment: I haven't had a problem with setting width and height at runtime via `LayoutPararms`. I terms of styles...yeah, well, there's a reason I don't use 'em. :-)

Comment: In Java you set the layout_width/height XML attributes by creating a layoutparams object and setting the Width and Height on it, then setting it either on the view or when adding your view to another view. The attribute name actually indicates exactly this: layout_width sets set width of the layout (rather than the view object that you give the attribute to).

Comment: I want to know why it's such a PITA to programmatically generate a UI

Comment: Took me ages to realise, that infact a few days ago I imported the wrong LayoutParams that didnt support Margins... Reading these answers I decided to remove my import. There are over 10 options D: I went for linearLayout.LayoutParams. Works.

Comment: He he.. I loved the last statement!!

Answer (score 33):

To add margins directly to items (some items allow direct editing of margins), you can do:

```
LayoutParams lp = ((ViewGroup) something).getLayoutParams();
if( lp instanceof MarginLayoutParams )
{
    ((MarginLayoutParams) lp).topMargin = ...;
    ((MarginLayoutParams) lp).leftMargin = ...;
    //... etc
}
else
    Log.e("MyApp", "Attempted to set the margins on a class that doesn't support margins: "+something.getClass().getName() );
```

...this works without needing to know about / edit the surrounding layout. Note the "instanceof" check in case you try and run this against something that doesn't support margins.

Comment: Its exactly I looking for.

Answer (score 25):

Due to variation in device screen pixel densities its good to always use `DIP` unit to set margin programmatically. Like below_

```
//get resources
Resources r = getResources();
float pxLeftMargin = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, r.getDisplayMetrics());
float pxTopMargin = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, r.getDisplayMetrics());
float pxRightMargin = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, r.getDisplayMetrics());
float pxBottomMargin = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, r.getDisplayMetrics());

//get layout params...
LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.setMargins(Math.round(pxLeftMargin), Math.round(pxTopMargin), Math.round(pxRightMargin), Math.round(pxBottomMargin));

//set margin...
yourLayoutTOsetMargin.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 13):

I have set up margins directly using below code

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourrelative_layout);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);            
params.setMargins(3, 300, 3, 3); 
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Only thing here is to notice that `LayoutParams` should be imported for following package `android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, or else there will be an error.

Answer (score 8):

```
 MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
 layoutParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
```

Comment: “While this code may answer the question, it is better to include the explanation of the code here.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
 LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 250;
params.leftMargin = 50;
params.topMargin = 50;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/*
 * invalid margin
 */
private void invalidMarginBottom() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) frameLayoutContent.getLayoutParams();
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    frameLayoutContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

you should be ware of the type of the view's viewGroup.In the code above, for example,I want to change the frameLayout's margin,and the frameLayout's view group is a **RelativeLayout**，so you need to covert to **(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)**

Answer (score 0):

Here a single line Solution:

```
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) yourLinearLayout.getLayoutParams()).marginToAdd = ((int)(Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density * yourDPValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Core-KTX:

```
 updateLayoutParams<RecyclerView.LayoutParams> {
                topMargin = 10
                rightMargin = 10
                bottomMargin = 10
                leftMargin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.left)
            }
```

---

Instead of RecycleView, use whatever your view is on ViewGroup.