# Android button in arbitrary position over RelativeLayout

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to build an android application that features a graphical display drawn within a RelativeLayout.  I want to place "+" and "-" buttons next to several of the parameters, which are drawn at various points on the canvas.  The positions are free-form don't seem to conform to any of the standard XML layouts.

I know how to create the buttons programmatically, but I don't know how to place them over the canvas where I need them to be.  I'm assuming that this would be done in the view thread's doDraw() method, after all the graphics have been drawn, but how?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem, and found out great [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically/3002321#3002321).

`RelativeLayout` rules like "leftOf" or "rightOf" can be implemented programmatically like this:

```
RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

Button weight = new Button(getApplicationContext());
final int WEIGHT_ID = 0;
weight.setId(WEIGHT_ID);
weight.setText("0.0");
LayoutParams wrapBoth = 
   new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
container.addView(weight, wrapBoth);

Button increaseWeight = new Button(getApplicationContext());
increaseWeight.setText("+");
// Note the difference: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  in spite of LayoutParams
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams toBeRightOfWeight = 
     new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
container.addView(parameter,wrapBoth);
// Sweet part
clearAirParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, WEIGHT_ID);
container.addView(increaseWeight, toBeRightOfWeight);
```

So, in code you can create a 'container' `RelativeLayout`, then add several `View`s with unique ID's and, finally, create `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` object to achieve sweet-like-sugar methods for alignment, like in XML.