# How to set layout_margin programmatically?

Tags: android, margins

I want to know how to set layout_marginLeft, layout_marginTop, layout_marginBottom programmatically using screen height and width. Please help me.

Thanks
Monali

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is an example (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically/3002321#3002321)):

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.setMargins(10, 20, 30, 40);

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("some text");
layout.addView(button, params);
```

Comment: thannks but i have 3 button and i have to set different margin to all 3 button. how can i do that?

Comment: I changed my answer and corrected a small mistake. Now it should be obvious.

Comment: u hav to create seperate params for each button

Comment: Exactly. This is the way how it works.

Comment: Thank u!!! 
Just I want to add small explanation:
p.setMargins(10, 20, 30, 40);//substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom