# Add margin to Button in activity

Tags: android

There's a setPadding(left, top, right, bottom) but is there a way to dynamically add a margin value to a button in android?

Comment: are you using Relative layout

Comment: yes I'm dynamically adding a button to a relativeLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is answered here  [Set margins in a LinearLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically)

It uses `layoutParams` and `layoutParams.setMargins`