# Set attributes in java

Tags: android, attributes, android-layout

In my layout xml, if I do something like `android:layout_marginTop="10px"`, how can I do that same thing in java?

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout rel=new RelativeLayout(this);
mWidth=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mWidth,mHeight);
Button mBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.xBtn);
params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mWidth, mHeight);
params.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
mBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
```