# how to manually set textview padding?

Tags: android, textview

This is java

```
maintitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_particularlatestnewstitle);
maintitle.setPadding(100, 0, 0, 0);
```

alllatestnewslist.xml here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_temp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:background="@drawable/background_news_list" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_alllatestnewstitle"
    android:layout_width="134px"
    android:layout_height="80px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_particularlatestnewstitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25px" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25px" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_newsdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="15px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_newscategorytitle"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="15px" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this xml, i have others object like image view and textview so on.

I set like this but it does not move 100 away from left........................

Any other way???????????????????????

Comment: can you add the xml for the whole layout? i suspect that that is where the problem lays

Comment: why dont you set it in XML file?

Comment: @Thepoosh, sorry for late update, please have a look, this is the entire xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of padding, change the margin.

edit: here, let me do it for you.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0); // margins as you wish

TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_particularlatestnewstitle);
myTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: a quick search would result to this stackoverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically

Comment: that one is linearlayout but i am not. Actually in the linearlayout, i still got textview and imageview

Comment: check out the answer with the most votes (from Mauro), instead of the accepted answer. I'm positive it fits to your situation.

Comment: I edited the answer. Check out the setLayoutParams method - should be exactly what you need.

Comment: still cannot. `LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   layoutParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0); // margins as you wish

   maintitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_particularlatestnewstitle);
   maintitle.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`

Comment: Careful - padding is not the same as margin. In CSS terms, padding makes the View bigger, margin makes the distance between Views bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your xml file you should make your `TextView` width to `fill_parent` if it is `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would never do it like this.
If you want to change padding etc. programmatically I'd always add the view programmatical aswell.
Thought that being said.

Have you tried to force it to update your view with .Invalidate() ?

Answer (score 0):

set its margin not padding if you want to move it as per my knowledge...

(Use dp instead of px wherever possible its just a suggestion). :)