# programmatically assign position to a button in android

Tags: android, button

Tell me how to programmatically assign a position to a button in android using linear layout. By default it takes the xtreme left position of the screen. Also i want to do it using Linear layout please do not suggest me using Relative layout. Following is my code

```
buttons_and_edittext=new LinearLayout(HelloAugmentedWorldActivity.this);
buttons_and_edittext = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
buttons_and_edittextParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(120, 150);

button3 = new Button(this);
button3.setText("log");

buttons_and_edittext.addView(button3,      
buttons_and_edittextParameters);
```

any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: refer the previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically

Comment: Thank u very much. I only had to use  buttons_and_edittextParameters.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

Comment: cau u suggest me a site wer i can get good tutorials on using Relative layout i sum what feel uneasy to use relative layout as i am new to android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer below link for add buttons into relative layout at fix position.

[Android User Interface Design: Relative Layout](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-relative-layouts/)

And Use Below Code also for that.

```
Button but1 = new Button(this);  
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);  
but1.setLayoutParams(params2);  
but1.setText("Press Here!");  
// give the button an id that we know  
but1.setId(1001);
layout1.addView(but1);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time I got a perfect solution to set button and image position programmatically in android studio with the help of relative layout params by following these steps - check out this [link](https://youtu.be/PynfI_9CSqA).