# Android: RelativeLayout issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to place a grid in the center of a RelativeLayout, but I don't want to use Gravity just because I need to put it on a specific position, using leftMargin and topMargin.

The grid is made using two LinearLayout's
I tried using this code, but I see the grid on the top left corner of the screen:

```
RelativeLayout fl = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams flp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    fl.setLayoutParams(flp);
    fl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);

    //Linear Layout to contain grid rows
    LinearLayout grid_layout = new LinearLayout(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    llp.leftMargin = (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this);
    llp.topMargin = (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this);

    //Set Params
    grid_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    grid_layout.setId(12);
    fl.addView(grid_layout, llp);

    Log.d("Display", "" + grid_layout.getHeight());

    //LinearLayout(s) ROWS
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

        llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ll.setLayoutParams(llp);
        grid_layout.addView(ll);

        //Cells
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) //Creating 4 cell blocks in a row
        {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
            tv.setHeight((int)Util.convertDpToPixel(42, this));
            tv.setWidth((int)Util.convertDpToPixel(42, this));

            ll.addView(tv);

            grid[i][j] = new CellBlock(grid, i, j, tv, null); //Building the game grid
        }
    }
```

It seems that these two lines:

```
llp.leftMargin = (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this);
llp.topMargin = (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this);
```

does not work! Why it keep to place the grid in the top left corner?

Thank you

Comment: did you check the return value of `Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this);` ?

Comment: I can't see it in your code, so try fl.invalidate () after all the layout changes

Comment: @ben75: Yes, I've checked the return value and it is correct..

Comment: @Andac: tried.. still the same..

Comment: Margins have to be set this way :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically

Comment: Double post... Just ignore this

Comment: @Andac: tried with this:llp.setMargins((int)Util.convertDpToPixel(100, this), (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this), 
(int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this), (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this));  But nothing.. Kinda weird..

Comment: in the for-loop you are overwriting your layoutparams ...
llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: yes, it is true, but that's not a problem just because I've already set them on my grid_layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llp.setMargins((int)Util.convertDpToPixel(100, this), (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this), (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this), (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this));
```

instead of

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llp.leftMargin = (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this);
llp.topMargin = (int)Util.convertDpToPixel(200, this);
```

for your RelativeLayout "grid_layout"

Comment: Ok, I think we're almost there! Now it works but the grid.. is not a grid anymore! I'll try to change something else..

Comment: ook! I only had to adjust the values! Now it works, thank you so much!