# how to put a margin between apps activity screen and display

Tags: android

I am new to android development. So, I'm having hard time on how to do this. My Activity Screen(Preferably Relative Layout) needs to have a bottom margin(say 1 dp) with the display screen. How can I do this programatically?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342269/create-and-set-margin-programmatic-for-relative-layout-android

Comment: Add android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" to your RelativeLayout, and please search for similar questions before posting here.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience..from next time I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a bottom margin by using `android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"`.

To do it programmatically...

```
// Setup your RelativeLayout
RelativeLayout yourLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_relative_layout);

// Set the margin
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) yourLayout.getLayoutParams();
yourLayout.bottomMargin = 1; // This sets the bottom margin to 1px
yourLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If you want to set it in pixels, you replace `yourLayout.bottomMargin = 1;` with:

```
yourLayout.bottomMargin = dpToPixels(1);
```

And add the following method:

```
private int dpToPixels(int dps) {
    if (dps == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
}
```