# Randomly place objects in an activity

Tags: java, android

So I'm new to java, and I have the basics of object placement down. I'm trying to design an app in which 5 objects are randomly placed in a certain activity. How would I go about randomly placing these objects?

Thanks!

Comment: which object do you mean ?

Comment: @mohammed monn, For example, a button

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: what are these objects, are they simple images(bitmaps) or some views ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom view that overrides the onDraw method.

Use Math.random or some other random number generating scheme to determine the x and y values of the bitmaps you are going to draw.

Then use Canvas.drawBitmap

Answer (score 0):

you can programmatically add your buttons to your activity with random position without using xml layout and here an example set buttons in activity

```
 LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
 ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 Button okButton=new Button(this);
 okButton.setText("some text");
 Random r  = new Random();
 okButton.setPadding(r.nextInt(), r.nextInt(), r.nextInt(), r.nextInt())
 ll.addView(okButton, layoutParams);
```

and here good thread to look at

[Set margins in a LinearLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically)