# How to a add button to view

Tags: android

I am developing a game, and I have a class that extended View(Not a xml file).
I want to add Button to my custom view, But my extended view has not addView method.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class has to extend [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), not View.

If you want to keep your class extend View you have the possibility to create an object which extends the ViewGroup (for example: LinearLayout, RelativeLayout...). Then put your costum view and the button into this ViewGroup.

Comment: If I do that, Does any problem occur?

Comment: i guess not, because a ViewGroup extends the class View. So you can use the same methods like in View

Comment: ViewGroup is abstract, and you will be forced to override onLayout to assign a position to every child of your ViewGroup

Comment: how can I give cordinate to the button?

Comment: googling is a simple solution. if your sdk is greater than 10 you can use button.setX / setY. if not you can use: button.getLayoutParams().topMargin = XXX. but u need an relative layout

Comment: I should I use onLayout like this object.onLayout(true,0,0,Screen width,ScreenHeight); ???

Comment: google and trying out helps more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically

Comment: Could I have your email address or messenger id to more help? cause i'm developing game!

Comment: you dont need my help. the internetm stackoverflow and the android documentations offer you a better and faster help