# LinearLayout setMargins programmatically has not effect

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, programmatically-created

Please have a look at the following code:

```
        LinearLayout ll1 = new LinearLayout(context);
        ll1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll1LayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll1LayoutParams.setMargins(100, 0, 100, 0);
        ll1.setLayoutParams(ll1LayoutParams);
        ...
        // parentLayout is FrameLayout
        parentLayout.addView(ll1, ll1LayoutParams);
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: what result are you getting? and what are you expecting?

Comment: No margin is added but I would expect a margin of 100. Any value has no effect 10 or 100 no effect

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically).This answer might help you

Comment: post your xml file containing the `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll1LayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams ll1LayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

When assigning layout params to a child, you must assign the LayoutParams class of its parent and not the view. Since here your parent view is a FrameLayout, you have to use FrameLayout.LayoutParams.