# android Imageview layoutparams in dip?

Tags: android, imageview, density-independent-pixel

I'm using the following code :

> ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
>
> i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
>
> i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
>
> ```
>        //pixels settings !!!
> ```
>
> i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 100));

but as you can see, it is setting the layout dimensions in pixels.

Does anybody know how to do the same thing but in "dip" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence

On how to convert from dpi to pixels.

Comment: thanks its look interesting to me but I dont understand the formula...

Do you understand it ? can you give me an example on how to convert 100dip to pixel for example ?

Comment: I found this solution that work perfectly : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-specify-dimensions-in-dip-from-java-code

Answer (score 19):

The following helper method takes as input device independent pixels (DIP) and returns actual pixels for the current device.

```
private int getPixels(int dipValue) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    int px = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                                            dipValue, 
                                            r.getDisplayMetrics());
    return px;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you store your dimension as a resource, you can use

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(id);
```

This will also make it easier to adjust your layouts.