# <uses-sdk> and ui problems

Tags: android, user-interface, android-manifest, resolution

Before, I didn't set the minSDKVersion in my manifest file and all works good.
But now as I'm using a ScaleGestureDetector, I'd like to set it:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

My phone is in 2.2 so the launch is ok, but when I'm on the activity which uses the ScaleGestureDetector, all the user interface is strange: it seems that it's displayed for another screen resolution !
The image I resize to fit the screen is smaller than the screen (but the ImageView in which the image is is at the good size), and the layout I set in the bottom of the screen is stretched (in fact its width is always the screen width but it's less heighter than usal).
What's the problem?

Comment: Do you set this layout in XML or code? Show us this snippet

Comment: both of them in fact :/ I tried to replace "fill_parent" with "match_parent" but that did'nt change anything.
The bottom layout is added to the main layout with (fill_parent,22), so the height should be the same, which is not the case ><

Comment: Your not helping much, without a code example it's just guess work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that your hardcoding 22pixels in your footer view height.

You'll be wanting to read this:

[What is the correct way to specify dimensions in DIP from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-specify-dimensions-in-dip-from-java-code)

Comment: well, the screen size didn't change so 22px are 22px, it should be the same height (and in code I can't give the layoutparams dps, just px). And that don't explain the image problems.

Comment: Your 2nd question: I like the way you read what I linked ... this would convert your 22px to the relevant dip.

Comment: oh, didn't see the link --' this work good for the bottom layout thx, i'll try the same trick for the image

Comment: but that sound strange.... the density of the screen can change with a different system version?

Comment: Nope but it removes that issue from the possibilities