# Give padding with setPadding with dip unit not px unit

Tags: android, layout, padding

The method

```
public void setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

someview.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
```

this will give padding with 1px in each side. How can I give 1dip instead of 1px ?

the values fro left , top right and bottom are in pixels , how can I give values programatically in code in dip ?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use following code to get pixels from given value in `dp`.

```
Resources res = getResources();
float value = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDP, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

where valueInDP is value in dp and this will return corresponding pixel value according to screen density.

or you can use following -

```
float value = valueInDP * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Comment: How would be the reverse ? from dip to px, is there any place where I can find more details

Comment: Yes. check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406449/does-setwidthint-pixels-use-dip-or-px and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-specify-dimensions-in-dip-from-java-code.

Comment: That value is in float, while the setPadding method requires integer parameters.

Comment: Why is this method still in pixels? I thought it's not recommended for ages by now to use pixels instead of dp. The whole point of dp is that it looks the same on all screens.

Answer (score 3):

[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android?lq=1)

```
float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dpAsPixels = (int) (your_dp_goes_here * scale + 0.5f);

view.setPadding(dpAsPixels , dpAsPixels , dpAsPixels , dpAsPixels );
view.setPaddingRelative(dpAsPixels , dpAsPixels , dpAsPixels , dpAsPixels );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getListView().setPadding(50,50,50,50);
```