# Corner Radius drawable shape

Tags: java, android, drawable, shapes

I'm dynamically creating a drawable shape in my list view and i'm setting the corner radius with this line of code.

```
setCornerRadius(float radius)
```

Am i able to specify this with a dp value somehow??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to get dip values dynamically?  This describes it:

[What is the correct way to specify dimensions in DIP from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-specify-dimensions-in-dip-from-java-code)

Copied from there:

```
int value = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                     (float) 123.4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```