# Drawing shapes in different sizes depending on resolution

Tags: android, resolution, scaling, screen-resolution

I am trying to write an app for android.
Therefore I've got a SurfaceView class drawing all objects.

Now, when for instance I'm drawing a circle, I have to specify a size.
Is there a way making this size depending on how big the screen resolution and density is?
Becausei when drawing a circle, I want it to be the same size on a lower resolution device as on a high resolution device.

When drawing a circle with 50px radius, it would be bigger on smaller screens than on bigger screens.

Any ideas?

EDIT: 
I know when creating some layout i could use density-pixels. But I am not working on layouts, i am drawing on top of a surfaceview. when drawing something like

```
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, size, paint);
```

size declares the radius in pixel. 
Is there a way to convert pixels into density pixels? Any method or simliar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't really want it to be **the same size**, but **the same aspect**. Because if the size is fixed (px), you then have density issues, as you noticed yourself.

Comment: use **density-pixel**, not just pixel

Comment: the problem is when trying to draw for example a sphere, it asks me for precise coordinates and a radius. When i type 

canvas.drawCircle(); 

It has to be a float as radius. when declaring it to 5, it will have a radius of 5 pixels, not density pixels. how can i convert pixels to density pixels in code?

Comment: This might be of use: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html

Comment: @fadden : going to check that, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the formula you are looking for (dip -> px) is published here:

[What is the correct way to specify dimensions in DIP from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-specify-dimensions-in-dip-from-java-code)